# Дублируются результаты SQL запроса

Tags: mysql

Работаю с запросом для выборки данных из нескольких одинаковых таблиц.
Один из запросов:

```
SELECT mens_wear.id, mens_wear.nomination, mens_wear.price, mens_wear.image_1 
FROM `mens_wear`, `mens_shoes` 
WHERE mens_wear.approve = mens_shoes.approve 
AND mens_wear.approve = 0 
LIMIT 6
```

Пробовал и Join. Эти запросы дублируют результаты выборки, каждая запись выводится по пять раз. Почему так происходит и как этого избежать.

Comment: Пример данных приведите, скорее всего потому что нельзя однозначно связать две таблицы.
А именно данные `mens_wear.approve` и `mens_shoes.approve` не уникальны.

Comment: Сложно судить не зная вашу структуру таблиц и заложенный в них смысл, но поле с названием `approve` заведомо равное нулю явно не похоже на условие объединения таблиц. Соответственно вы получаете декартово произведение правого набора строк на левый.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не просто `JOIN`, а `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT mens_wear.id, mens_wear.nomination, mens_wear.price, mens_wear.image_1 
FROM `mens_wear`
LEFT JOIN `mens_shoes` ON mens_wear.approve = mens_shoes.approve 
WHERE mens_wear.approve = 0 
LIMIT 6
```