# Дублируются данные в SQL запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос следующего вида:

```
select t.type_name, m.name, o.width, o.height, o.price 
from orders as o
join db_product as p on p.id = o.product 
join db_type as t on t.id = p.type
join db_material as m on m.id = p.material 
join client as c
join orders_group as og where og.client_id = $id and c.id = og.client_id
```

Где `$id` выбирается динамически из выпадающего списка. Вот, что выдает запрос при id = 29, и где должно быть ровно шесть строк:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть каждая строка дублируется по четыре раза. Пробовал и `LEFT JOIN` как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914668/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0), но это никак не повлияло на запрос. Как это можно исправить?

Вот схема базы данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd.: Таблица orders
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Distinct пробовали ?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич в данном случае допустимы повторяющиеся строки, поэтому distinct не подойдет. Здесь где-то ошибка в самом запросе.

Comment: *и где должно быть ровно шесть строк* Мы не верим. Показывайте исходные данные, которые вместо "должных 6 строк" продуцируют 24.

Comment: @Akina добавил содержание таблицы orders

Comment: @teran clients добавил, чтоб в условии where мог к нему обращаться. Я пробовал join client as c on c.id = $id но это тоже не меняет ничего

Comment: `o.order_group_id = og.id` случаем не забыто?

Comment: @teran вот оно и забыто. Спасибо большое! Если можно, отметьте ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из представленной схемы данных видно, что в условиях выборки отсутствует условие связи таблиц `orders` и `orders_group`:

```
 o.order_group_id = og.id
```

*зы: лучше писать нормальные left/inner join с условиями.*

Answer (score -1):

Избавиться от дубликатов можно, добавив в запрос DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table 1
```